# Cross Domain Ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, nginx

I have a requirement which is getting cross domain json data via Ajax. I need to maintain 2 different server (Server A and Server B).

Server A only contain static contents.
ie: JS, Images, Css

Server B only contain dynamic contents
ie. php driven scripts

According to above requirement I have set up and successfully configured Nginx + Apache environment in my local pc.

I have a two domain run on my local host.

Server A : `http://localhost:9000/` > running on Nginx as a front end for static content

Server B : `http://localhost:8888/` > running on Apache as a back end for dynamic content (i.e. php)

*Server A contain*

index.html
jquery and 
custom Ajax handling java script.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="./js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8888/drp/application/ajax.php';
        var success = function(data){
        var set = "";
            set += "Name: "+ data['fname']+ " " + data['lname']+"<br>";
            set += "Age: "+ data['age']+"<br>";
            set += "Address: "+ data['address']+"<br>";
            set += "Email: "+ data['email']+"<br>";
            set += "Web: "+ data['web']+"<br>";
            $('#result').html(set);
    };

    var error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //alert(errorThrown);
            alert('errorThrown');
    };

    $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',   
          url: url,
          data:{todo:"jsonp"},
          dataType: "jsonp",
          crossDomain: true,         
          cache:false,
          success: success,
          error: error
    });
});
```

Server 2 contain ajax.php which is handle the Ajax request

ajax.php

```
<?php
#header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');



$x = array(

    'fname' => 'Jone',
    'lname' => 'Max',
    'age' => '26',
    'address' => 'London,Uk',
    'email' => 'jone.max@test.com',
    'web' => 'http://jonemaxtest.com',

);

print json_encode($x,true);
?>
```

When I am calling this front end index.html, I can see an error like this

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement 
{"fname":"Jone"...}
```

I tried so may time but I did nor get correct result. every time I get this kind of error message. also I have tried to change  header('Content-Type: application/javascript'); into header('Content-Type: application/json'); but did not work.

where I did my mistake in that code set...?

Please help me.!

Answer (score 2):

Try returning a string from the server which is like:

```
$data = json_encode($x);
echo "/**/my_callback($data);";
```

Where data is your JSON encoded array.

And don't forget to remove the header for the content type.

In your JavaScript in the Ajax request, on success:

```
function (data) {eval(data);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using jsonp. It's designed for cross domain use.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/learn-how-to-use-the-jsonp-data-format-with-jquery.html#fbid=3qCzdTpgxJX

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your code

- You have to set the `dataType="json"` instead of `"jsonp"` in your ajax call since you are passing `json`

  The corrected code is below

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
      var url = 'http://localhost:8888/drp/application/ajax.php';
          var success = function(data){
          var set = "";
              set += "Name: "+ data['fname']+ " " + data['lname']+"<br>";
              set += "Age: "+ data['age']+"<br>";
              set += "Address: "+ data['address']+"<br>";
              set += "Email: "+ data['email']+"<br>";
              set += "Web: "+ data['web']+"<br>";
              $('#result').html(set);
      };

      var error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              //alert(errorThrown);
              alert('errorThrown');
      };

      $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',   
            url: url,
            data:{todo:"jsonp"},
            dataType: "json", 
            crossDomain: true,       
            cache:false,
            success: success,
            error: error
      });
  });
  ```

  - In your `ajax.php`  you have set header as `application/javascript` , but your data is `json` so change it to              `application/json` and you should also add another header to allow cross Domain `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`.

    Here is the corrected code

    ```
       <?php
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $x = array(

         'fname' => 'Jone',
         'lname' => 'Max',
         'age' => '26',
         'address' => 'London,Uk',
         'email' => 'jone.max@test.com',
          'web' => 'http://jonemaxtest.com',

         );

           print json_encode($x,true);
          ?>
    ```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: Hello Sarath

your fixes is exactly correct. it is working for me. thank you very much.